# UseState loads previous state when value changes (NextJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, use-state

I am creating an e-commerce app and on the Shop page I want to implement filters based on category and price. I have set the state like so:

```js
const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
  cat: "",
  price: "",
});
```

And this is the select tag and the options to trigger the change for the category:

```js
<select className="outline-none" name="category" onChange={handleChange}>
  <option value="start">-</option>
  <option value="Hoodie">Hoodie</option>
  <option value="T-Shirt">T-Shirt</option>
  <option value="Sweatshirt">Sweatshirt</option>
</select>
```

This is the `handleChange` method:

```js
const handleChange = (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  if (value === "start") {
    setProductsF(products);
  } else {
    setFilters((prevFilters) => ({ ...prevFilters, cat: value }));
    const testArr = [...products];
    const filteredProd = testArr.filter(
      (prod) => prod.categories[0].name === filters.cat
    );
    setProductsF(filteredProd);
  }
}
```

The problem is, when the `handleChange` fires the filters get the previous value and are not updated correctly. Let's say I change the values to "Hoodie" then "T-Shirt". When I click on "Hoodie" the shopping list is empty and when I click on "T-Shirt", I get the list of hoodies. I get the products from static props and I am setting the filtered products on this state:

```js
const [productsF, setProductsF] = useState(products);
```

What is the way to get the correct filters values when the user selects an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to use the updated `filters` state right after you "updated" it. Don't forget that `useState` is asynchronous just like `setState` in class components. You can't update the state on one line and assume it's already changed on the next one. You'll likely use the unchanged state.

Instead of `filters.cat`, you can use the `value` you receive. This way you update both the `filters` and the `productsF` state.

```js
const handleChange = (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  if (value === 'start') {
    setProductsF(products);
  } else {
    setFilters((prevFilters) => ({ ...prevFilters, cat: value }));
    const testArr = [...products];
    const filteredProd = testArr.filter(
      (prod) => prod.categories[0].name === value,
    );
    setProductsF(filteredProd);
  }
};
```